# can't get bean to show on jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I've got a bean called User.java.

In the DAO, (from the database) it pulls a field called classRegistrationDate, and sets it to User.classRegistrationDate.

I created a Boolean called isRegistrationLocked, and if the registrationDate is before 12/20/2014, I set it to true, else it's set to false.

Bean:

```
public Boolean isRegistrationLocked= false;

public boolean getIsRegistrationLocked() {
    return isRegistrationLocked;
}

public void setRegistrationLocked(boolean isRegistrationLocked) {
    this.isRegistrationLocked= isRegistrationLocked;
}
```

DAO:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date classRegistrationDate= user.getClassRegistrationDate();
Date releaseDate= df.parse("12/20/2014");

if(classRegistrationDate.before(releaseDate))
{  fi.setRegistrationLocked(true); }
else
{  fi.setRegistrationLocked(false); }
```

Data has been verified, and the values are being passed and set correctly.

In the jsp, I need to show and hide a  based on the value of isRegistrationLocked.

JSP:

```
<html:hidden property="user.isRegistrationLocked" value="${user.isRegistrationLocked}" />

<c:if test="${user.isRegistrationLocked eq false}">
    <tr>
        <td class="text"> FALSE </td>
    </tr>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${user.isRegistrationLocked ne true}">
    <tr>
        <td class="text"> TRUE </td>
    </tr>
</c:if>
```

But the value comes across as false all the time, so it's not being accessed properly.
I've tried just outputting the value using  and nothing even shows; it appears in the html as a blank.

Where am I going wrong, and how can I get the value over to be evaluated?

Comment: What is the date returned from the database

Comment: true eq false is false and true not equals true is also false,... tip: either put a breakpoint in the getter method or just write the value to the jsp, to verify.

Comment: If you replace `public Boolean isRegistrationLocked= false;` by `public Boolean isRegistrationLocked= true;` will you always get a true in your jsp? If you might not being accessing the instance you believe.

Comment: Try renaming your getter to isRegistrationLocked instead of getRegistrationLocked ?

Comment: @Brovoker, I have 2 dates for my true/false test - 12/1/2014, 12/23/2014. Renaming didn't work either.

Comment: @StephaneM, yes, I'll always get a true if changed, but when I try a cout, I can't even print the value. So I don't think I'm correctly accessing the value. The value's being set correctly though, as I do printlns in the DAO, and it's correct. Just not correct when I try to access it in the jsp.

Answer (score 0):

if u want get smth with `${}` u should put it to request. Unfortunately  i don't now what u use for processing requests. Can advise 2 ways:

1)Servlets/JSP.

put object to request:

```
request.setAttribute("user", User);
```

2)Spring Controller.
put object to model, smth like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String user(HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
    ***
    Configuring "user" object
    ***
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "redirect:/*to your jsp*";
}
```